# Apply angular velocity to wheel via plugin

Tags: skid-steer, gazebo-plugin

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi, I'm trying to implement a skid steer plugin (I can't use the already implemented one), but I have some problems. I was able to apply a linear velocity to the whole model using:

```
this->model = _parent;
model->SetLinearVel(math::Vector3(.03, 0, 0));
```

but I wasn't able to select one of the wheels (also which is the type of a link element?) nor to apply an angular velocity to it. I've tried with this:

```
left_front_wheel = _parent->GetEntityByName("left_front_wheel");
```

This is the SDF of one of the wheels:

```
        <joint type="revolute" name="right_back_wheel_hinge">
        <pose>0 0 0 0 0 0</pose>
        <child>rigth_back_wheel</child>
        <parent>chassis</parent>
        <axis>
            <xyz>0 1 0</xyz>
        </axis>
    </joint>
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/13975/apply-angular-velocity-to-wheel-via-plugin/) by [Hanteus](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2724/hanteus/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 13 on 2016-07-23

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I was able to do it with the following lines of code:

```
private: physics::JointPtr leftFrontWheelJ,oint;
    
this->model = parent;
leftFrontWheelJoint = this->model->GetJoint("left_front_wheel_hinge");
leftFrontWheelJoint->SetVelocity(0, .1);
```

The parameters of SetVelocity are the index of the axis on which you want to apply the velocity and the velocity itself (I write this for people who may have my same problem).

---

Originally posted by [Hanteus](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2724/hanteus/) with karma: 13 on 2016-07-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [guido_sanchez](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2902/guido_sanchez/) on 2016-11-16**:
Have a look at https://github.com/gmsanchez/gazebo_stuff/tree/master/WheelSpeedPlugin

It is a plugin that applies each of the two wheels of a differential drive robot a velocity received on vel_cmd topic. The code has two standalone programs to test if it works. You can also check the differential_drive.world model where it was tested.

Cheers!